# Query font-awesome element in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

In my render method I have

```
<span onClick={handleDelete} className="delete-action">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash-alt" />
</span>
```

Using react-testing-library how can I access the above span element.
This is what I tried so far

```
getByText(<FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash-alt" />)
```

but the error says matcher.test is not a function. How should I approach this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get this error because `getByText`'s first argument is a [TextMatch](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#textmatch), but you passed a component.

Apparently, you can pass a `title` prop to `FontAwesomeIcon` since [this commit](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/commit/5d7af386c036064cb3f46e0b6aa40cb26939c9fa) :

```
<span onClick={handleDelete} className="delete-action">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash-alt" title="some title"/>
</span>
```

and then you can simply get your component using

```js
getByTitle('some title');
```

NB : `title` prop is not set as an attribute of the `i` element generated by font awesome, but rather as a `title` tag related to the `SVG` element, but `react-testing-library`

> Will also find a title element within an SVG.

ref : https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytitle

Comment: This is nice. Be aware if you've set up a global mock for @fortawesome/react-fontawesome (as I had) it won't work, unless you update your mock to something like this:
```
import React from "react"

export function FontAwesomeIcon(props) {
  let className = `fa ${props.icon}`
  return <i className={className} title={props.title} />
}
```